# What is the shapes of 'bent' handrail and 'angled' handrail?

Tags: meaning

I searched Google images but that wasn't helpful...
What is the shapes of 'bent' handrail and 'angled' handrail?
what's the defference?

Comment: Where did you see the terms? Is there a link to the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bent**

A curvature from the beginning till the end.

**Angled**

A corner in an exact point between the beginning and the end.

So what you are looking for if there are certain points in each step between you may say it is angled but if it's curved as a whole and has no such points you may say bent.

An example in graphics; (sorry for my paint skills)

[image: sorry for my paint skills]

For ***bent*** closest shape is **circular** while for ***angled*** closest shape is a **triangle** or **rectangle**. You can notice **angle** in the names easily..

Comment: Also, if something is accidentally damaged, you might say it's "bent", but "angled" would only be used for something that is intentionally shaped to have an angle.